# Unable to understand Install script (sql script) in Magento

Tags: magento, attributes, sql-update

I am adding attribute by updating sql script, like this,

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->addAttribute('customer_address', 'group_id', array(
'label'        => 'Address group',
'visible'      => true,
'required'     => false,
'type'         => 'int',
'input' => 'select',
'source' => 'address_group/address_attribute_source_group',
'user_defined' => 1,
'position'  => 100
));

.
.
.
$installer->endSetup();
```

I am unable to understand what is meant by following line, I am unable to find any explanation about it

```
'source' => 'address_group/address_attribute_source_group',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to comment on your post. Trying to understand if you have copied this code from somewhere. From your code I understand that you want to add a "Customer Address Attribute" named as "customer_address"

'source' => 'address_group/address_attribute_source_group'

The implication of the above is the path. You should have a folder/file path as below:

> /app/code/local/Address/Group/Model/Address/Attribute/Source/Group.php
>
> Group.php:
> class Address_Group_Model_Address_Attribute_Source_Group ...

Since, this attribute is of TYPE => "SELECT", you should be having the options array in this file "Group.php"

Options Array should be something very similar to:

```
public function toOptionsArray() {
    
    return array(
        array(
            'label' => '',
            'value' => ''
        ),
        array(
            'label' => Yes,
            'value' => 1
        ),
        array(
            'label' => No,
            'value' => 0
        )
    );
}
```

Let me know if you got it!

Happy to Help!

Happy Coding...

Comment: I got it, but my class is Like this,'class Address_Group_Model_Address_Attribute_Source_Group
    extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Table
{
}'

Comment: And '**Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Table**' have nothing like **toOptionsArray()**

Comment: You will have to create this function in Group.php with your values in that.

Comment: Because `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Table` uses database table where it keeps all options added by admin in the attribute configuration form. It uses `getAllOptions` to fetch them.

Comment: agreed with Zefiryn.. You can choose to use XML to add your values similar to default magento. However, DO NOT update the CORE files directly.

Answer (score 1):

It points to the class that provides options for the attribute. As attribute uses `select` input it requires options to be provided. This class is created by calling `Mage::getModel()` and passing the value of source to it. To find the class you need to find node `models/address_group` in `config.xml` files of the available modules. This will provide class prefix. Next what comes after slash is added to that prefix in order to create class name. So in this case it will resolve to something like `Company_AddressGroupModule_Model_Address_Attribute_Source_Group`. This class need to implement `toOptionsArray` method that returns an array in the following format:

```
array(
    array('value' =>  'option_value', 'label' => 'option_label'),
    ...
);
```

Comment: I got it, can see my comments given bellow